# Sets of vectors that span a space with binary coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm looking towards using sets of vectors which span the null space of a matrix to conceptually interpret an aspect of the transformation encoded by the matrix.

In this regard, a basis for the null space can be easily constructed using procedures like reduced row echelon factorization or singular value decomposition.

Several articles propose procedures to find sparse "basis". A related question can be seen to be [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253995/how-can-one-construct-a-sparse-null-space-basis-using-recursive-lu-decomposition).

Are there spanning sets (consider the matrix to be in $\Bbb  Q$) which have coefficients in $\{0,1 \}$ in other words, they are "binary" ?

Can this spanning sets, if they exist and there exists a procedure to find one, be found minimizing a certain criteria ? Specifically, sparsity and/or cardinality.